# How to unit test a multipart POST request with Spring MVC Test?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit

I am trying to create unit test for REST APi but having big trouble with the uploading excel method.

Here is the method on the controller side

```
@RestController()
@RequestMapping(path = "/upload")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")

public class FileController {
@Autowired
FileService fileService;

@PostMapping(value = "/{managerId}/project/{projectId}")
public List<Task> importExcelFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile files, @PathVariable int managerId,
        @PathVariable int projectId) throws IOException, ParseException {

    return fileService.getTasksFromExcel(files, managerId, projectId);
}
```

Whatever I try I get a lot of errors and evidently I don't really understand what I am supposed to do.

The main error I get is

```
current request is not a multipart request
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following.

I just simplified your example a tiny bit.

So, here's the controller that returns the file size of the file it receives.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/upload")
public class FileController {
    @PostMapping(value = "/file")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> importExcelFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile files) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(files.getSize());
    }
}
```

and this one is the test of it. There is a class called MockMvc that Spring provides to easily unit test your controllers and controller advices. There is a method called [multipart](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html#multipart-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) that you can use to simulate file upload cases.

```java
class FileControllerTest {

    private final MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(new FileController())
            .build();

    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    void importExcelFile() {
        final byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("TEST_FILE_URL_HERE"));
        mockMvc.perform(multipart("/upload/file")
                .file("file", bytes))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string("2037")); // size of the test input file
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful

Comment: How does this work considering the `@PathVariable` values ? I cannot make it work in MockMvc when using `@PathVariable`

Answer (score 0):

Generally Multipart uploads can be tested via MockMultipartFile:
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/file-upload-test.html